# How to save and load the trained CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

After training of the convolutional neural network how to save and load the model?
Just new to this field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is something you learn by following the documentation and tutorials of tf/keras, and it has been answered before many times here.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Keras or Tf:

To save model:

```
model.save("my_model.h5", include_optimizer=True)
```

To load and compile model for example:

```
model = keras.models.load_model("my_model.h5")
model.compile(optimizer=your_optimizer, loss=[loss1, loss2, ...], metrics==[metrick1, metrick2, ...])
```

Comment: Thanks at lot. Do I have to compile every time I load the model?

Comment: When I am loading the saved model.h5 file from my local folder to google colab I am getting following error in spite of providing correct path. 
----> 8 model = keras.models.load_model("D:/Test/model.h5")
--> 209             raise IOError(f'No file or directory found at {filepath}')
    210           if saving_utils.is_hdf5_filepath(filepath) and h5py is None:
    211             raise ImportError(

OSError: No file or directory found at D:/Test/model.h5

Comment: Yes you need to compile every time. About error: in colab you need to change path to model from 'D:/Test/model.h5' to 'model.h5' if model and script one directory .

Comment: Guys please help. I am new to this field. This is an OS Error. It seems the way I am providing path is not correct.  What changes should I make. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew. My colab notebook and model.h5 both are google drive. Still I am getting the message "No file or directory found"

Comment: Whenever I am executing this command in a new colab notebook always it gives path problem (No file or directory found at new_model.h5). Can I load 'my_model.h5' in a new colab notebook and predict?           
model = keras.models.load_model("my_model.h5")

Comment: I kept the "my_model.h5"  in the same folder of my google drive where google colab notebook is there. Now getting the error that unable to open the file.  OSError: Unable to open file (truncated file: eof = 14680064, sblock->base_addr = 0, stored_eof = 269856360). Kindly please to rectify the problem.

Comment: May be file not completely upload or crashed by uploading. Try upload file one more time.